# UV-spectrophotometer analytical method for doxycycline hyclate and tylosin tartrate powder

Tags: everyday-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I am trying to detect tylosin tartrate from the mixture of doxycycline hyclate using $\pu{0.01 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$ as solvent, and waveleghth of $\pu{290 nm}$ for detecting tylosin tartrate in UV-spectrophotometer but the method fails

The aim is  finding an analytical UV-spectro photometer  method to detect tylosin tartrate in mixture of doxcycline hyclate ?